# Gap between line and marker

Tags: plotting, marker

i am doing very simple thing when I run this line:

```
ListLogPlot[Table[1/x, {x, 10^Range[-2, 1, .1]}],PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True]
```

I get following plot. There is a gap between line segments and markers.
[image]

Any idea where does it come from?

Comment: Can't reproduce it in 11.3 and 12.0 on Windows 10 32-bit.. Which version of MMA do you use?

Comment: I tried both 11.3 and 12

Comment: See https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcbn9r0glldsgql/plot.pdf?dl=0